Is there any way to make QEMU faster when debugging with gdb?
I'm using xv6 on ubuntu with VMWare. and I'm trying to debug xv6 with gdb on qemu.
Usually it runs pretty fast when it's not debugging(not using gdb), but when I use gdb qemu prints the single line for appromixately 10 seconds, and qemu prints about 30~40 lines when it's booting, so the whole booting section needs about 5 minutes.
That's way TOO long. I don't have that much time to sit down and wait for 5 minutes to type a single word.
Is there any way to make this faster?
$ ./dbgrun.sh
... (qemu is on)
$ gdb kernelmemfs  
... (gdb is on)
(gdb) set archi i386:x86-64
...
(gdb) target remote localhost:4321
...
(gdb) c
Continuing.

... waiting for ages to see $ pops up in qemu...

I think it's not normal to wait this long time to type.
+Edit
I added dbgrun.sh code below, I hope this helps identify the problem.
qemu-system-x86_64 -bios /usr/share/ovmf/OVMF.fd \
    -drive if=ide,file=fat:rw:image,index=0,media=disk \
    -S -m 2048 -smp 4 \
    -gdb tcp::4321 \
    -serial mon:stdio \
    -vga std 


You should tell us what is in your 'dbgrun.sh' script, because chances are quite high that whatever the slowdown is it's because of something in that.

I added dbgrun.sh code into question. hope this helps

Thanks. Hmm, there's nothing obviously odd in that script, so I'm a bit confused about why it's slowing down a lot.
